# How to create a virtual record field for Entity Framework lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I'm trying to define some models that I use in Entity Framework 6. I would like to use F# records. If I put `[<CLIMutable>]` above the record definition and use `ICollection<'a>` for, well, the collections. EF works fine.

I can store and retrieve the records. However for EF to do lazy loading I need to make the record field containing the collection virtual. I can make a property member virtual by making it abstract and providing a default. Records are not classes. Is it possible to make a record field virtual?

If I try to augment the record with an abstract member I get this error `this declaration element is not permitted in an augmentation`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot define a virtual member in a record - this makes sense, because you also cannot inherit from a record, so why would you need virtual members.

But I can see why this would be needed for Entity Framework. Perhaps it would make sense to have something like `CliVirtual` attribute, akin to `CliMutable` (especially if this happens often). Feel free to suggest this at the [F# uservoice page](http://fslang.uservoice.com/)!

So, I guess your best option is to use ordinary class with virtual auto-implemented properties (which looks significantly uglier):

```
type A() =
  abstract member Id: int with get, set
  default val Id = 123 with get, set
```

Or perhaps see if some of the other SQL type providers for F# let you do the same thing more nicely!

Comment: Thank you. Have suggested it. http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6672675-an-clivirtual-attribute

Comment: It was moved to https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/360 and declined. At least now you can reference it from GitHub.