# Entity Framework Identity managment in F#

Tags: entity-framework, f#, asp.net-identity

So I have a user class based on the Entity Framework Identity model:

```
type ApplicationUser() = 
    inherit IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>()
    let mutable id = 0
    member this.GenerateUserIdentityAsync (manager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>) =
        manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
    [<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>] override this.Id with get() = id and set(v) = id <- v
```

and I also have a list of external identities (e.g. Facebook):

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type ExternalIdentity = 
    {
        [<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>] Id : int
        [<Required; MaxLength(128)>] ExternalUserId : string
        [<Required; MaxLength(128)>] Provider : string
        UserId : int
        [<ForeignKey("UserId")>] User : ApplicationUser
    }
```

I would like to add a navigation property to the list of external identities.  But every time I try to augment the `ApplicationUser` type, I get "This declaration element is not permitted in an augmentation".

My latest attempt is this:

```
type ApplicationUser with
    abstract member ExternalIdentities : ICollection<ExternalIdentity> with get, set
```

but this will not compile.

Please don't tell me I will have to go back to C# to make this work.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of an *abstract* member here?

Comment: It's so that it can be overridden by Entity Framework.  F# doesn't have a virtual keyword.  However, this doesn't compile as it is.

Comment: This is based on Tomas's answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775760/how-to-create-a-virtual-record-field-for-entity-framework-lazy-loading  I have omitted the `default` implementation, but that doesn't allow it to compile.

There is a solution to all this, but Entity Framework wasn't designed with things like record types and non-cyclical dependencies.  I'll post my solution when I've worked it out, but I must admit I'm not all that confident that it can be made to work smoothly.

Comment: As `ApplicationUser` is a class and not a record you could define the navigational property in the class and link the class and record definitions using `and`. I'll post an answer tonight... writing this using my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For defining mutually dependent types in F# there is the `and` keyword:

```
#I @"..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.1\lib\net45"
#I @"..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\"
#r "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll"
#r "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll"
#r "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"

open Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
open Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

type ApplicationUserLogin() = inherit IdentityUserLogin<int>()

type ApplicationUserRole() = inherit IdentityUserRole<int>()

type ApplicationUserClaim() = inherit IdentityUserClaim<int>()

type ApplicationUser() = 
    inherit IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>()
    let mutable id = 0
    member this.GenerateUserIdentityAsync (manager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>) =
        manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
    [<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>] override this.Id with get() = id and set(v) = id <- v
    member val ExternalIdentities : ICollection<ExternalIdentity> = upcast [||] with get, set


and [<CLIMutable>] ExternalIdentity =
    {
        [<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>] Id : int
        [<Required; MaxLength(128)>] ExternalUserId : string
        [<Required; MaxLength(128)>] Provider : string
        UserId : int
        [<ForeignKey("UserId")>] User : ApplicationUser
    }
```

Comment: That is brilliant!